# cannot resolve junit android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, junit

I used to create a new Java Library in Android Studio to study the book Agile Java. This is my code.

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
public class StudentTest extends TestCase {
    public void testCreate() {
    }
}
```

At first everything goes well. But when I run the Studio the next day it says

> "cannot resolve symbol junit"

even I delete the Module and create a new one it still doesn't work.

What's wrong with it? Should I change an IDE?

The build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I didn't edit the build.gradle at first because it could run well.

Comment: no no don't change the ide! Have you tried, clean-rebuild-run cycle?

Comment: It would help to see the Gradle build script of your project.